# Detect if method is executed as a thread

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multithreading

```
class Foo():
    def bar(self):
        try:
            # do something
        except:
            # log and continue
        finally:
            Timer(9001, self.bar()).start()

def main():
    foo = Foo()
    foo.bar()
```

My understanding is that the first call to Foo.bar() will be blocking, but then Foo.bar() will spawn another instance of itself as a separate thread.

I want the program to fail hard if the initial non-threaded call to Foo.bar() fails (i.e., if any of the “do something” bits fail) for any reason. If the later threaded calls fail, I just want to log it and keep trying until one of the threaded calls succeeds.

I figured I would try to detect if the method is being executed in a thread, but I am unsure of how to proceed.

Comment: If any of the `do something` bits fail, that last line won't get executed, so no new threads will be started.  You have a couple problems in your code, though.  `bar()` should take a `self` argument and should call itself with `self.bar()`.  `main():` needs a `def` at the beginning.

Comment: @zondo: My bad, I left out a lot of details. Edited to more closely reflect the actual code. I want to the whole program to fail hard if the initial `#do something` fails.

Answer (score 0):

Detecting if you are still in the same thread can be done by checking thread-local data:

```
import threading

class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.thread_flag = object()
        mydata = threading.local()
        mydata.thread_flag = self.thread_flag

    def bar(self):
        mydata = threading.local()
        if hasattr(mydata, 'thread_flag') and mydata.thread_flag is self.thread_flag:
            raise Exception('Fail hard!')
        Timer(9001, self.bar()).start()
```

Note that you have to call `.bar()` in the same thread where you created the `Foo` object.

But I suppose it would be easier for you to simply keep track of a number of calls to `bar` instead. And fail hard on `1`. Going down the "detecting thread" road can be very tricky and lead to unpredictable issues.